# ASP.NET Configuration granularity between Machine-level and Site-level?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I want to be able specify to do the following:

- Specify configuration settings such as appSettings and connectionStrings for multiple web apps in IIS7
- No editing Machine.config or the machine-level web.config
- Web apps are distinct web sites in IIS (not subfolder apps)

Is this possible without just duplicating the configs for each app?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear... do you mean that you want multiple web sites to SHARE a web.config so that you can make changes to multiple sites in one place?

Comment: I don't think sharing a web.config would be appropriate given the diversity of the applications themselves. Rather, I'd want them to all inherit their settings from a single place, much like they already inherit from the machine-level configs. From what I've seen, I'm not sure this is possible - I'm just hoping someone else knows about something I don't.

Comment: Not possible.  This is precisely what the default ASP.NET web.config is for... so why are you excluding that as an option?

Comment: Because I don't want to have to manage the same config across a dozen different apps.

Comment: By "default" I meant machine-level web.config that is found in the Framework/CONFIG directory.  Why can you not use that?  You are basically asking for a feature which already exists and then saying you can't use it.